# Python URL Extractions from Chrome History

Tags: python

I have been using the following code to try and extract URLs from a copy of my chrome history, i have been writing this in PyCharm:

```
import sqlite3
import os

PATH='C:\\Users\\%s\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History - Copy' % os.environ.get('USERNAME')

HistCop = sqlite3.connect(PATH)

c = HistCop.cursor()

ccp = c.execute('SELECT url FROM urls ORDER BY "id" DESC LIMIT 5')

ccpp=ccp.fetchall()

print ccpp
```

My main goal is to open this up at least one url in a browser, but when I use the code:

```
import webbrowser

url = ccpp[4]

webbrowser.open(url)
```

I end up with an error. I think it does not work because ...

```
(u'https://stackoverflow.com/search',)
```

there is a "u" in front of it.

Please let me know why this happens, if there is a way to get rid of it, or if there is a better way for my goal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want us to help you, you should include in your question the original, complete error message, and all the code needed to reproduce the problem. For example, how did you obtain `(u'https://stackoverflow.com/search',)`? Is it `ccpp[4]`? Don't make us guess!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're passing a tuple into a function that expects a string. `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples (since a row with *n* elements is represented as an *n*-tuple), so you just need to get the single element contained in the tuple:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
url = rows[4][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlite's `fetchall` method returns a list, which contains an item per row in the result of the query. These items are each a tuple (similar to a list) which contain the field data for that row. So:

```
ccpp # this is a list
ccpp[4] # this is a tuple
```

You can tell it's a tuple because the output you printed shows that. If you want the data from the first column, the 'url' column, you need to index it (similar to how you would a list):

```
ccpp[4][0] # get the first column of the fifth row
```